# using android studio 2.1.2 and getting the error "execution failed for task app clean"

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.1

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.

> Unable to delete file: C:\Users\GULSHAN BHAGAT\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\blame\res\debug\multi\values-am.json

Comment: Weird, have you tried deleting it manually? Checked permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `build` folder from project package explorer and then run it.

I hope it will help you...

Answer (score 1):

Check that the file is not in used by other process (maybe and editor or similar), try to delete that file manually or delete the complete `build` folder